# making a footer stick to the bottom of the page

Tags: css, sticky-footer

I am having a nghtmare with some code on a site I am making, should be pretty simple but it isn't proving so.

I want my footer to stick to the bottom of the page, but for all the content to come first (when there is more than a page worth, if that makes sense)

I have been able to do it in Safari, Chrom and Firefox but suprise suprise Internet Explorer is proving to be the main problem.

Am at a point now where it is on the bottom however the footer appears over the content of the page when there is alot (See the 'Who we are' tab).

http://www.break-comms.com/index.html

I would really appreciate any help whatsover on this as it is really begining to annoy me, been going back an fort changing code for a good few hours now.

Below is the CSS that accompanies the page, like I said any help on this would be REALLY appreciated.

```
* {
    border:0px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#html {
    height:100%;
    }


#banner {
    padding: 5px 0px 10px 0px;
}

#container {
    width:970px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;

}
#nav {
    margin-left:0px;
    text-indent:0px;
    text-align:center;
}

#menutab li {
    display:inline;
    list-style-type:none;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:100;
    text-align:center;


}

#menutab a {
    color:#9ea3ab;
    padding:5px 32px 5px 32px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
}

#menutab b {
    color:#9ea3ab;
    padding:5px 0px 5px 0px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
}


#menutab a:hover {
    color:#28957f;
}

#social .socialImage{float:right;

}

.divFloat {
float:right;
padding:0px 5px 0pc 0px;
}

.clear {
clear:both;
}

#social {
    background:transparent;
}

#footer {
    Position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:970px;
    height:45px;
    background-image:url(images/footer.gif); width:970px; height:45px;
}



#footermenu .footermenu{float:right;

}

#footermenu li {
    display:inline;
    font-family:Arial;
    list-style-type:none;
    font-size:16pt;
}

#footermenu a {
    color:#9ea3ab;
    font-family:Arial;
    padding:0px 5px 0px 0px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:right;

}

#footermenu a:hover {
    color:#28957f;
}

.clearfooter {
    height:45px;
    clear:both;
    }
#address {
    color:#28957f;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:16px;
    text-indent:5px;
}

#address2 {
    color:#9ea3ab;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14px;
    text-indent:5px;
}

#contentbackground {
    background-image:url("images/homebackgroundimage.gif"); width:970px; height:400px;
}

#contentbackgroundcontact {
    background-image:url("images/contactbackgroundimage.gif"); width:970px; height:330px;
}

#contentbackgroundyouth {
    background-image:url("images/youthbackgroundimage.gif"); width:970px; height:350px;
}

#contectbackgroundwhoweare {
    background-image:url("images/whowearebackgroundimage.gif"); width:970px; height:700px;
}

#contentbackgroundmusic {
    background-image:url("images/musicbackgroundimage.gif"); width:970px; height:360px;
}

#contentbackgroundbrand {
    background-image:url("images/brandbackgroundimage.gif"); width:970px; height:500px;
}

#content {
    color:#9ea3ab;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:5px 30px 5px 50px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:top;
}

#content2 {
    color:#9ea3ab;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:5px 30px 5px 70px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:top;
}


#contentcontact {
    color:#9ea3ab;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:16px;
    padding:5px 30px 5px 50px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:top;
}


h1 {
    color:#9ea3ab;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:16px;
    padding:5px 30px 5px 35px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:top;
}   





body {
    height: 100%;
    background-image:url("images/denimbackground.gif"); repeat;
}
```

Comment: Please post only relevant code.

Comment: Sorry, but I believe I can witness the problem in FF and Chrome as well. I'm not convinced this is just a matter of X-Browser compatibility.

Comment: it would be better if you put this code online. and only post relevan code here

Answer (score 2):

Works for me if I remove the position:absolute in the #footer CSS directive.
Including in IE.

Comment: Same results here when I follow Alain's instructions. :)